# Transcode HLS m3u8 to MP4 and include text track

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Is it possible with FFMPEG to convert a m3u8 to a MP4 and keep the captions (text) track?

When looking at the Apple stream, https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/bipbop_4x3_variant.m3u8  I see that the video stream makes mention of Closed Captions, but I can't seem to find a way to extract them.

```
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, smpte1
70m/smpte170m/bt709), 400x300, Closed Captions, 29.92 fps, 29.92 tbr, 90k tbn, 1
80k tbc
```

The multiple attempts I have made transcode to mp4 but it drops the captions.

I have used VLC on the manifest and it has "subtitles" but after transcode the mp4 doesn't.

Used the command:
`ffmpeg -i https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/bipbop_4x3_variant.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc out.mp4`

Answer (score 5):

I did manage to pull together enough pieces on information to complete this.  It is a combination of 3 commands.

**Using ffmpeg version 2.8.4**

#### First, the playlist segments need to be merged into a single MPEG-TS file:

`ffmpeg -i [playlist_url].m3u8 -c copy [filename].ts`

#### Next, we need to extract the Closed Captions from the file:

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "movie=[filename_from_last_step].ts[out0+subcc]" [filename].srt`

**Note:** I could only get it to work if the ts file and the cmd's current path matched.

#### Lastly, you merge the ts and srt file and transcode to MP4:

`ffmpeg -i [filename_from_first_step].ts -i [captions].srt -c:v copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -c:s mov_text [out_file_name].mp4`

This will give you a MP4 with the captions embedded, as well as a stand-alone srt file if your player doesn't support embedded captions.

Comment: Thanks for the formula! It works on a stream I needed to download. But I am not entirely sure what is the second bracket of `[filename_from_last_step].ts[out0+subcc]` for?

Comment: @jackxujh closed captions are embedded in the video frames, `[out0+subcc]` allows ffmpeg to extract them and treat it a independent track.

Answer (score 1):

If Closed Captions means a CEA-608 or 708 stream, then those are weirdly packetized i.e. embedded *within* the video stream, and ffmpeg [cannot](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1778) copy or encode them.

You can try to use [CCextractor](http://www.ccextractor.org/) to extract them. If it does not work on the stream. Download the individual segments, concat them and try with that.

Once extracted, you can encode them using `-c:s mov_text` into the MP4.

Comment: Point 1 and 3 are dead on, but point 2 can be done with `ffmpeg` as I finally found a bug with the solution.